# How do I fix the "Index out of range" error in Python?

Tags: list, indexing, range, out

I am trying to create a record from a list of 6 items. The error tells me that rec[1] is out of range.

```py
pay = open("paymast.txt","r")
sal = open("saltyp.txt","w")

heading = pay.readline()

for rec in pay:

    rec = rec.split(",")
    
    id = rec[0]
    name = rec[1]
    gender = rec[2]
    code = rec[3]
    grade = rec[4]
    salary = rec[5]
    salary = salary.strip('\n')
    
    record = id+","+name+","+gender+","+code+","+grade+","+salary

    if int(salary) < 1500 and gender == "M":
        
        sal.write(record)

pay.close()
sal.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check your file `paymast.txt`. I've tried with an array of string, formatted as `"id,name,..."` and the split works fine, the only time that it raises an `IndexError` is when the input is bad formatted.

For example:

```py
pay = ["1", "0,ted,male,4,23,1440\n",
       "2,katie,female,1,2,240\n"]
# The first index should raise the error

for rec in pay:
    rec = rec.split(",")

    id = rec[0]
    name = rec[1]
    gender = rec[2]
    code = rec[3]
    grade = rec[4]
    salary = rec[5]
    salary = salary.strip('\n')

    record = id+","+name+","+gender+","+code+","+grade+","+salary
    print(record)
```

Raised error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 9, in <module>
    name = rec[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```